# why git commit --amend make confliction happened? that is quite strange

Tags: git, version-control, git-push, git-commit, git-amend

```
*   84b134d - (HEAD, origin/lab_master, lab_master) comment macro defination which is protent to be a fun
|\
| * 735d88f - add small script to ease ctag related option (13 minutes ago) 
* | 6623a94 - add small script to ease ctag related option (4 minutes ago) 
|/
* 0d0913a - add gitignore to ignore ctags file (57 minutes ago)
```

735d88f is a --amend commit, but conflict happened at this moment, why?

i have only one pc, and i always edit files on it, also i have only one local repo, what's more this repo is only used by here, **i think there is no  possibility that conflict may happen**?

but it happened, why?

Comment: looks like you have made two branches with near identical changes on them, (same commit message). Looks as if you changed branches between the initial commit and the 'amended' commit causing grief.

Answer (score 9):

It is best to amend only commits you have not already pushed to your server. Once you push a commit, if you try to amend it and push it, it will result in a conflict because you have changed history (as recorded on the server).

Comment: He is working alone. He doesn't have these issues. You are correct in cases where you are collaborating, but even then, it's not as evil as people said it was.

Comment: @adam-dymitruk Even one person working alone can end up with a merger of multiple versions of history, if they have more than one computer/repo.

Having seen a fair few people on the #git IRC channel who have managed to merge together large amounts of rewritten history in a corporate setting, and who are now in an amount of trouble, I really do think the call to be over-cautious is justified.

Comment: The better advice is not to use `git pull` and inspect history after `git fetch` with `git log ...origin/currentbranch`. If you are blindly pulling each time, then you are right. But that is not recommended.

Comment: @MarkGranoff seems you got it, so why i cannot amend to a pushed commit?

Comment: @Adam Dymitruk i commit, then push, then amend ... as Mark said

Comment: @hugemeow My experience is that I can amend my last commit any time. But if you amend the last commit that you have already pushed, the server will complain when you push again because you are overwriting its history. The rule of thumb I use is that I only amend commits that I have not already pushed. If already pushed, make a new commit and push that. Then there are techniques to squash multiple commits into one, but that's another topic. :-)

Comment: @MarkGranoff how to know local commit is pushed or not?

Comment: @hugemeow `git status` will show you if your local report is "ahead" of master or not. If you are ahead, then you have one or more commits that have not yet been pushed.

Comment: Do you have any remotes defined? If not, that may explain it. You are the remote, in that case, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an example of the conflict. What you have done is made the same change from the same point in time and then merged them. Either way, you can fix this by squashing all that into one by

```
git tag finalstate 84b134d
git stash -u
git reset --hard 0d0913a
git checkout finalstate -- .
git add -A
git commit -C finalstate
```

if the "comment macro" commit and the second "add small script" commit is valid you can

```
git tag finalstate 84b134d
git stash -u
git reset --hard 6623a94
git checkout finalstate -- .
git add -A
git commit -C finalstate
```

instead. If you want the second one instead, then

```
git tag finalstate 84b134d
git stash -u
git reset --hard 735d88f
git checkout finalstate -- .
git add -A
git commit -C finalstate
```

remove the helper tag after with

```
git tag -d finalstate
```

if you pushed after the second commit, then ammended, then pulled, then you would have a merge with the conflict. Not sure why you don't have a separate commit for that merge with the conflict resolution. You probably did more work while in conflicted state, fixed the conflicts, added all changes and committed. In this case, the last set of instructions that I wrote will help you.

Comment: the conflict happens after 0d0913a and 84b134d  is the commit after i solved the conflict